# Socialite con facebook error al loguear despues de registrar

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

estuve usando Socialite para Laravel y siempre me tira un error luego de intentar loguear el usuario recien registrado. Si yo actualizo la pagina y quiero loguearlo ya funciona perfectamente. Pero no logra registrar y luego loguear automaticamente.

[image: error al loguear el usuario luego de registrarlo por primera vez en la base de datos]

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'facebook_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

register.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Socialite;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        // 1 check if the user exists in our database with facebook_id
        // 2 if not create a new user
        // 3 login this user into our application


        try
        {
            $socialUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        $user = User::where('facebook_id',$socialUser->getId())->first();
        if(!$user)
            User::create([
                'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
                'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
                'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),

            ]);

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->to('/home');





        return $user->getEmail();

        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel utilizas?

Comment: La version 5.3 .  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás definiendo la variable `$user` cuando el usuario no existe, o sea cuando se registra:

```
    $user = User::where('facebook_id',$socialUser->getId())->first();
    if(!$user)
        $user = User::create([
            'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
            'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
            'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),

        ]);

    auth()->login($user);
```

Comment: Mil gracias, era eso!